# MongoDb replica set: How do I verify data replication on other servers?

Tags: replication, mongodb

I have a 3 member replica set running. It's geo-located on 3 separate VPSs. On primary I can do rs.status() and see it's working. I can't execute any mongo shell commands on the secondaries. How do I verify data replication on other servers? I see nothing indicating data being copied in the logs.

Thanks a lot for any help :-)

**Edit 1:**

Tried db.printSlaveReplicationInfo(). Logged in as user with full admin role...

[image: Admin user not authorized]

**Edit 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For querying secondary run the following command first. After running this, you can do all regular stuff on secondary.

```
rs.slaveOk()
```

To see the replication status, run the following command on primary. This will show you if the secondaries are up to date or lagging.

```
db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Abhay, thanks for the idea! I tried it and posted my screen above. What do you think? Oops... switched to admin db and logged in again and it worked. I'll post the screen in sec...

Comment: After logging in admin db, looks like the replication info shows it's sync'd. Is that what that reads?

Comment: Looks like it's synced. BTW, rs.slaveOk() is needed if you want to query secondary.

Comment: Thank you Abhay! I've learned a lot about MongoDb the last couple months. Still figuring it all out ;-)